# Allow p:selectOneListbox within h:form but without submitting value to a bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:selectOneListbox` within an `h:form` but without the `value` attribute becuase  I need to use it only for presentation purposes (only for showing another inputbox, but value submit is not required for this component). But when I try to submit the form using `h:commandButton`'s `actionListener` that is unsuccessful unless the component's value is binded to a bean using `value` attribute.

How do I submit the form without needing to specify the `value` attribute for this `p:selectOneListbox`?

```
<p:selectOneListbox >
      <f:selectItems ... />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

Is there any way I could tell what components to exclude from being processed instead of telling what all to process(as that would bloat up the code unnecessarily with a long list of ids
) ?!

Comment: You could try to submit the form with ajax (f:ajax or p:commandButton) and process all elements except the `selectOneListbox`. Not sure if this would work, but you can give it a try.

Comment: yes I can perhaps specify ids of  all the components to process in the `process` attribute but that would bloat up the code unnecessarily with a long list of ids, just to exclude a single id. Is there any way I could tell what components to exclude from being processed instead of telling what all to process ?!

Comment: Perhaps primefaces partial submit feature(v 3.3.1) will help this.

Comment: Why not putting the listbox in a different form?

Comment: this listbox is to be displayed on the page in between the submit form  button & other input components. So for the presentation purposes this could not be moved out to different form

Comment: Then you could use css to put it in the right place (physically).

Comment: like how, if you can give some hint.. ?

Comment: Added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `p:selectOneListbox>` into another form and then change its position via css:

```
<h:form id="otherForm>
  <p:selectOneListbox style="position: relative; top: -50px"">
      <f:selectItems ... />
  </p:selectOneListbox>
</h:form>
```

This will move the selectBox 50px up from its normal position.

It is a kind of dirty solution and you have to fiddle to find the correct position but it should work.